# How to force a value to be within a range?

Tags: python, range

What is the most "pythonic" way to do this?

```
x = some_value
bounds = [lower_bound, upper_bound]

if x < bounds[0]:
    x = bounds[0]
if x > bounds[1]:
    x = bounds[1]
```

Comment: `x = min(upper_bound, max(lower_bound, some_value))`?

Comment: Honestly, your second if 'could' be an 'elif'. But for the most part it is perfectly alright the way it is.

Comment: okay, thanks, im just getting used to the python way of doing things, and sometimes get carried away with finding a tricky way to do do something in one line, hehehe

Comment: @jonrsharpe: would calling the min and max functions over two ifs make much of a difference in performance? its for an optimisation algorithm which will be called many times

Comment: @guskenny83 Is your question about performance or being pythonic? These are two things often incompatible.

Comment: @guskenny83 test it and find out - I'd expect `if`/`elif` to be faster than the function calls. There seems to be little point in creating `bounds`, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: thanks for your help, i might just stay with the if/elif then - you would imagine that the max/min functions would be using something like an if/elif statement anyway. It is just too tempting to do things in a single liner sometimes. Also, bounds was only created for the sake of an SSCCE, in the full implementation it exists already as a two dimensional list of bounds for each index of a list of variables.

Comment: @guskenny83 ah, I see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...and sometimes get carried away with finding a tricky way to do do
>   something in one line.

The most important thing when programming is that you really understand the problem you want to solve. And then you want to write code, that can be read. So, pythonic does not mean it is a one-liner...

And this is not ugly or bad Python:

```
if x < lb:
    x = lb
elif x > ub:
    x = ub
```

And this is the way I would suggest to write what Naman Sogani suggested.

```
_, x, _ = sorted([lb, x, ub])
```

Comment: `_, x, _ = sorted([lb, x, ub])` This is something new to me, thanks! Is this implementation faster?

Comment: Faster than what you suggested? I don't know, I think it's clearer. Personally I like if/elif solutions. And speedwise I guess every solution here takes a ms or so...

Answer (score 5):

This looks quite better to me

```
x = sorted([lower_bound, x, upper_bound])[1]
```

However if you want to consider performance, then `if/elif` is the best implementation.

Comment: It looks somewhat trickier to me, but the intention of what you try to achieve is not as easy to spot (at least to me), so I would find it less pythonic - and harder to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
x = max(min(some_value, upper_bound), lower_bound)
```

This is pythonic because it's a terse one liner, and it's more efficient than creating a list and sorting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care what the value is as long as it's within a certain range:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(range(lower_bound, upper_bound))
```